# WebStorm PhpStorm code reformat: how to fix comments?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

WebStorm and PhpStorm allow you to [reformat your code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/reformatting-source-code.html) to fit the coding style set in settings (e.g.: indentation space)

I'm using this measure to fix some of the many lint errors in my project but I'm stuck at one point: is it possible to reformat all `//` comments to begin with a space? To go from

```
//My comment
```

to

```
// My comment
```

If a comment already begins with a space character, it should be left alone.

Edit: There is an option in:

- *"Settings >> Editor >> Code Style >> {{coding lang}} >> Other tab"* to set a blank space at the start of each comment (see "*Comment code*" section at the bottom of this image).

[image]

However, even with that selected, using the *"Reformat code"* option does not fix the comments.

Comment: This is probably something you should ask on SuperUser instead, since it's not really related to coding.

Answer (score 6):

**'Add a space at comment start'** option only affects **'Comment with line comment'** action (`Ctrl+/`) behavior, it is not used by formatter.

There is currently no way to insert leading spaces on formatting, please vote for [WEB-26244](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26244)